# Would Google Checkout be satisfied with wildcarded SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-checkout

I wonder whether there should be any problems with Google Checkout if I register SSL certificate for wildcarded domain (e.g.  "*.example.com"), given that root certificate is still given by one of [the following guys](https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=57856)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last we recieved wildcard certificate and it seems to work quite nice with Checkout. Note that our root certificate is signed by Thawte, that is one of those guys from question.